# Get the job and sequencer list in Datastage 8.5

Tags: datastage

Is there a way to list out all datastage jobs and sequencers available on a server?We are working on test server.I want to store the jobs and sequencers information in some excel or text file.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Please look here for an example using the Admin Console

```
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21618535
```

You may also be able to run the commands from the bin/uvshell, but I've not done it this way.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access on Admin client then -
You can search and export from designer tool also. Search '*' which includes everything and filter by job type and export the output.